# Can't get the cityname of a particular area in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, geocode

In my app i have used google map, based on the latitude and longitude successfully i can get the Area,Sate,pincode, country, my code is below

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(Map.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    try {
                        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(draggedlat, draggedlng,
                                1);
                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                            Log.d("CityName", "---->"
                                    + addresses.get(0).getLocality()
                                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)
                                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2)
                                    + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName());

                            Log.d("Locality", "Locality"
                                    + addresses.get(0).getSubLocality());

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Map.this,
                                    "Try with some other city..",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Now my problem is have to find the city name of a particular area. is that possible?? kindly help me.

My OutPut Is:

```
VanapatlaVanapatla, Andhra Pradesh 509235,India,Kollapur Rd
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What returns this line: addresses.get(0).getLocality()

Comment: Refer this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getLocality%28%29

Comment: check it out my output.

Comment: Still it returns nothing.. then Try to test with other coordinates to see if it returns something.

Comment: i have tried but this is the output i got for all location, which means the same form of output(Area, state, pincode, country)

Comment: Hope VanapatlaVanapatla was your city??

Comment: No thats an area which is pointed by my marker.

Comment: Then what is your city from your output??

Comment: if i located my pointer in AnnaNagar(one of the areas in chennai), then i need to get the city name as chennai. can you get me what exactly i want.

Comment: Yes addresses.get(0).getLocality() this line returns city name.. try with another GeoPoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with different points:

```
List<Address> list = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location
            .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    if (list != null & list.size() > 0) {
        Address address = list.get(0);
        result = address.getLocality();
        return result;
```

Comment: i have used this but no luck. got same output

Comment: i got a solution through ( list.get(0).getSubAdminArea(); ) this method.. anyway thanks for your details.

Comment: Great...but getSubAdminArea() wont returns city name always. It Returns the sub-administrative area name of the address

Comment: [Address[addressLines=[0:"Bajanaikoill St",1:"Appur R.F., Tamil Nadu 603204",2:"India"],feature=Bajanaikoill St,admin=Tamil Nadu,sub-admin=Kanchipuram,locality=Appur R.F.,thoroughfare=Bajanaikoill St,postalCode=603204,countryCode=IN,countryName=India]]                    This is the overall list of a adress,  "sub-admin=Kanchipuram", through sub admin we can get the city of the particular area.